# Inserting Data to MySQL using PDO for PHP Xcode

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, pdo

I am really struggling trying to understand why the below code does not insert the date I am sending?

```
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "passwrd";
$dbname = "dbname";


$conn  = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Last = $_POST['Last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$userID = $_POST['userID'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Name, Last, email, password, userID) VALUES (:var1, :var2, :var3, :var4, :var5) "; 

$q = $conn -> prepare($sql);

$q -> execute (array(':var1' => $Name,
               ':var2' => $Last,
               ':var3' => $email,
               ':var4' => $pwd,
               ':var5' => $userID));

?>
```

If instead of

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
```

and so on ... I hard code the values, so I might have:

```
$Name = 'Jane';
```

It adds the data to the database, but with $_POST, it fails at the execute line.

My Xcode looks like:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver/AddUser.php?Name=%@&Last=%@&email=%@&pwd=%@&userID=%@", Name, Last, email, pwd, userID];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I have gone through numerous tutorials and questions in SO and I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know anything about Xcode, but looks like a GET request to me.  If that's the default and would explain why `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: @AbraCadaver what do you mean? Put GET instead of POST? I am sending data from my iPhone app to a sql server ...

Comment: @user3079872 `print_r($_POST)` to see if you have any values or not.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you are absolutely correct, it works with GET instead of POST.

Comment: @Alex, yes there were no values, but I could not work out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTTP request is being sent using the GET protocol, but you are accessing your data using the POST protocol.  You have three potential fixes,

1. Change PHP to read data using GET

   $email = $_GET['email'];
2. Change PHP to be agnostic to mode (my preference)

   $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
3. Change your iPhone app to send using post.

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation. I have now put $_REQUEST and it is inserting the data into the database. Out of interest, how would I change the app to send using POST?

Comment: You must configure the NSMutableURLRequest object you provide to the initWithRequest:delegate: method and construct the body data.   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

Comment: thanks very much, makes a lot of sense! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though you're issuing a `get` request, not a `post` request, which means your `$_POST` is undefined, which is probably what's causing PDO's errors you're seeing. Instead, you should retrieve the values from the `$_GET` global variable:

```
$Name = $_GET['Name'];
$Last = $_GET['Last'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
```

Comment: thanks very much. I have tried $_GET and it works. I have gone with the $_REQUEST rather than $_GET.